# C++: Using a proxy class to make a member function call in the non proxy class

Tags: c++

I am currently working on a class where in a get function, I must return a reference to one of the members. Then, after this member is changed through the = operator, I also want to make a call to one of the classes member functions.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
  public:
    A() : member(0)
    {}
    int & get_member()
    {
      needed_call();
      return Aproxy(this);
    }
    void needed_call()
    {
      std::cout << "Ran call: " << member << std::endl;
    }
  private:
    int member;
};

class Aproxy
{
  friend A;
  public:
    Aproxy(A * ap): _ap(ap) {}
    A & operator=(const int & i)
    {
      _ap->member = i;
      _ap->needed_call();
    }
  private:
    A * _ap;
};

int main(void)
{
  A a;
  a.get_member() = 5;
}
```

The problem here is that both classes need the definitions of the other class to perform this task.

If this program worked, it would print out the following

> Ran Call: 0
>
> Ran Call: 5

Is there a way to do this? Is this even possible?

Comment: (1) Forward-declare your classes **and** (2) define member functions out-of-class.

Comment: DOH, Thanks. I feel stupid now.